# Bullet Collision

Tags: c#, xna

I am making a 2D shooter in Xna 4.0

I have a bullet in my game and i'm trying to get it to collide with an enemy but when i try to check if its position is equal to the enemy it doesn't

Bullet shooting:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace Moba_Turtle1
{
    class Bullet
    {
    Texture2D bulText;

    float timer;
    float interval = 2;

    public bool shot = false;

    public Vector2 velocity;
    bool canChange = true;

    public Vector2 position;
    public Vector2 lastPosition;
    Vector2 orgin;

    public Bullet (Texture2D newText, Vector2 newPos)
    {
        bulText = newText;
        position = newPos;
    }

    public void Update (GameTime gameTime)
    {


        if (Moba_Turtle1.Character.direction == true && canChange == true)
        {
            canChange = false;
            velocity.X = 50f;
        }

        if (Moba_Turtle1.Character.direction == false && canChange == true)
        {
            canChange = false;
            velocity.X = -50f;
        }


        position = position + velocity;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(bulText, position, null, Color.White, 0f, orgin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
    }
}
```

}

Collision check:

```
foreach (BeeAi bee in Bees)
        {
            {
                if (bullet.position == bee.position)
                    bulCol = true;
            }
        }

        if (bulCol == true)
            bullets.Clear();
```

PLEASE HELP!

Comment: I don't see the C code your tags are talking about.

Comment: When this become a C?

Comment: Looks like the bullets increment by a value of `velocity`, so maybe they skip right over the position of `bee`?

Comment: Could it be that the positions aren't exactly equal and that you need to do something like `bullet.position - bee.position < margin_of_error`?

Answer (score 1):

```
bullet.position == bee.position
```

`position` is a `Vector2`, which is made of `float` co-ordinates. It is extremely unlikely that the bullet and the bee will be in exactly the same position to the accuracy of a float!

You need to re-think your collision detection along the lines of whether two bounding rectangles overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Don't compare floats because unless they are exactly the same they will not be equal. So if you are calculating the position you won't get a match. You should test whether the bullet position is within a small range of values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as someone else mentioned, that you will almost NEVER hit EXACTLY the same position as the bee.

an easy fix can be to make your loop like this:

```
foreach (BeeAi bee in Bees)
{
    foreach (Bullet bullet in bullets)
    {
        if ((bullet.position - bee.position).Length() <= 10f)
        {
            bulCol = true;
        }
    }
}
```

but this can also fail quite easily, if the speed of the bullet is high enough.

I suggest you look into Ray, BoundingSphere, BoundingBox and Rectangle.

If your bullets are always moving horizontally ONLY or vertically ONLY, then the easiest and best fix is to make a rectangle that spans the distance the bullet has moved the last frame, and use Rectangle.Contains or something.